# Refactoring a PHP class

Tags: php, class, methods, refactoring

I am playing with refactoring a PHP class. My original class had a constructor and one large method that ran a string through various operations and spat out the result at the end.

```
class String
{
    public function __contstruct()
    {
        // a couple of initialisation things
    }

    public function make($string)
    {
        // very large method that does lots of different types of filtering to an input string
    }
}
```

My class gets run through scrutinizer-ci and one of the things it was suggesting was to refactor the large method into smaller self contained methods using the Composer method pattern.

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/refactorings/compose-method

I have done this and it does seem neater, but here is my problem/query...

My new class now looks something like this

```
class String
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // a couple of initialisation things
    }

    public function make($string)
    {
        $string = $this->smallMethodOne($string);
        $string = $this->smallMethodTwo($string);
        $string = $this->smallMethodThree($string);
        $string = $this->smallMethodFour($string);
        $string = $this->smallMethodFive($string);
    }

    private function smallMethodOne($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }

    private function smallMethodTwo($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }

    private function smallMethodTwo($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }

    private function smallMethodThree($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }

    private function smallMethodFour($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }

    private function smallMethodFive($string) {
        // do some stuff
        return $string;
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if there was a better way of organising the `make()` method as it doesn't *feel* correct doing it like that, just running a bunch of methods in sequence.

Comment: Well, without knowing your logic and purpose and the real code, we cannot give you much.

Comment: As far as I can tell you, you could separate each "work unit" into a separate method. If they make no sense when separated you could always keep them in the big large one (but I would consider separating them for readability if they're properly documented). This "step1", "step2", "step3" sequence feels familiar to me (mostly 'cos of my poor analysis skills) but please, do consider if it makes sense to you... If the first method converts the string from state A to state B and the second from state B to state C, they should be separate.

Comment: You can see the original class here - [link](https://github.com/JayBizzle/Safeurl/blob/master/src/Jaybizzle/Safeurl/Safeurl.php)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Answer (score 16):

What you should ask yourself is: how hard would overriding a single "smallMethod" be without changing other "smallMethod"s behavior?

If you can override a single "smallMethod" without touching others, you are likely doing the correct thing.

Say you have this:

```
public function deleteMe()
{
    if($this->a == x || $this->b != y){
         $this->cache->delete($this);
         $this->storage->delete($this);
         $this->refs->unlink($this);
    }
}
```

Now what if you want to extend the class and change the `deleteMe()` if() condition?
You will need to totally rewrite the method, for a one line change. That's not convenient at all.
Instead:

```
protected function checkDeletability()
{
    return $this->a == x || $this->b != y;
}

protected function internalDelete()
{
     $this->cache->delete($this);
     $this->storage->delete($this);
     $this->refs->unlink($this);
}

public function deleteMe()
{
    if($this->checkDeletability())
         $this->internalDelete();
}
```

This way, you can override single pieces of the procedure, without touching others. That's basically why you "split a big method into smaller ones".

So, check if you are satisfied with this. That's what matters most!

Comment: In the example code block should $this->internalCheckDeletability() be $this->checkDeletability() perhaps? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like this :

```
public function __construct($string)
{
    $this->string = $string;
    // a couple of initialisation things
}
public function make()
{
    if(!$this->smallMethodOne()){
        return false;//or custom exception or array with status/description
    }
    ...
    if(!$this->smallMethodFive()){
        return false;//or custom exception or array with status/description
    }

   return $this->string;

}
private function smallMethodOne() {
    // do some stuff
    $this->string = $new_string;
}
```